# retrieve the text in a specific cell in a QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I've been trying to use QT4 with a QTableWidget to store data. I seem to be unable to select a cell and get the text out of it and wanted to see why it won't retrieve it.

```
ui->QTableWidget->item(ui->QTableWidget->rowCount(),0)->setText("");
```

Answer (score 14):

[QTableWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtablewidget.html) uses indices which are zero based, so `qTableWidget->rowCount()` is one past the end of your table.

To iterate over your items and see their text, you could do something like this:

```
// assuming #include <QtDebug>
for (int i=0; i<tableWidget->rowCount(); ++i)
{
    qDebug() << tableWidget->item(i, 0)->text();
}
```

Comment: executing this causes the program to crash:
qDebug()<<ui->tableWidget->item(0,1)->text();

Comment: Have you added anything to the list?  If not, item(0,1) will return NULL and the attempt to dereference the NULL pointer to get the text will result in a crash.

Comment: How do I add something to the list? I've been creating a row that's it, I though the row would have blank cells when created. How do I assign values into those new cells when inserting a row?

Comment: @eyecreate, when you create a row it adds that row to the count, but it doesn't add any items for the row.  You'll need to do that yourself.

Answer (score 3):

It seems I didn't realize that I had to make a new Item object for each cell. I solved this by initializing it "empty"

```
ui->tablewidget->setItem(ui->tablewidget->rowCount()-1,0,new QTableWidgetItem(""));
```